# What is the time complexity of finding the minimum element in a min heap?

Tags: c++, heap, min-heap

I was reading Problem1 (Part-b) mentioned in [this document](http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.006/oldquizzes/solutions/q2-f2009-sol.pdf):

> Finding the minimum element of a binary min heap takes logarithmic time:
>   **T**/**F**?

It should be true, because when we construct a max-heap, the time complexity is `O(logn)`as mentioned [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/pop_heap/).

Similarly, if I construct a min-heap, it should be `O(logn)`. A min heap is analogous to max-heap, its just that in C++, by default a max heap is constructed, and we will have to write a custom comparator for min-heap. Then, what's the difference?

Comment: `pop` is `O(log n)`, `get` is `O(1)` though.

Comment: Right, the minimum element is stored at the root, and hence it's `O(1)`, and removal of minimum element will be `O(logn)`. Right.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The time complexity to find the minimum element in a min-heap is `O(1)`, that is the primary purpose of such a container. It was literally made to find the smallest (or largest) element in constant time. The operation that is `O(logn)` is *insertion*. As others have mentioned, `pop` is also `O(logn)` because it will remove the smallest (or largest) element, and then force a re-ordering to ensure that the new smallest (or largest) element is now at the top of the heap.

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue)

> A priority queue is a container adaptor that provides **constant time lookup** of the largest (by default) element, at the expense of **logarithmic insertion and extraction**.

For all intents and purposes, a min heap and a max heap are the exact same thing except for the comparator. In fact, in practice a min heap is generally a [`std::priority_queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue), and if you want a maxheap you use `std::less` and if you want a minheap you use a `std::greater` for the `Compare` template argument

```
template<
    class T,
    class Container = std::vector<T>,
    class Compare = std::less<typename Container::value_type>
> class priority_queue;
```

Comment: extraction (`pop`) is also O(log n). cppreference's wording is poor here, `top` is the one that's constant time, I'm not sure anybody would refer to `top` as "extraction"

Comment: @Barry I agree with you, I would say that "extraction" implies `pop`, and in that case their wording is wrong.

Comment: I fixed the wording on there.